# NullPointer Exception in Struts application

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I want to create a struts app which displays index.jsp file which contains link to the search.jsp file.Directory structure  of Struts 1.2 app is as below

**Struts 1.2 Directory Listing**

[image]

The content of **web.xml** is as below

```
      <display-name>MiniHR</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  
  <jsp-config>
   <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://struts.apache.org/tags-html</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>    
  </taglib>
   </jsp-config>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

The contents of **struts-config.xml** is as below

```
<global-forwards>
    <forward name="search" path="/search.jsp"></forward>
</global-forwards>
```

The content of **index.jsp** is as below

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<body>
    Add Employee<html:link forward="search">Search Employees</html:link>
</body>
```

Now when i run this app on eclipse its displaying **HTTP Status 500 -** as below

[image]

I tried few solutions but nothing seems to fix the problem.A Little Help would be appreciated.

I have added the war file in following URL

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g6daddfa41e8981249992832312c465146f9b6bc45

Thank you

Comment: `web.xml` file that you have mentioned, is it the full content of web.xml file?

Comment: yes that's the full content I tried to add struts-config in init-param but its not working any suggestions

Comment: Where is the struts action servlet mapping in your web.xml?

Comment: can you post the changes in web.xml so that i will try out I tried that let me edit my answer

Comment: The root cause of the problem as it says is :
`NullPointerException in
 TagUtils.computeURLWithCharEncoding exception`
What i see the problem may be with `struts-tld` version.

Comment: I see exclamation on your project, there might be classpath problem, fix it.? And can you post your `search.jsp`?

Answer (score 1):

Struts assumes that all requests go through the Struts ActionServlet, which you aparently have not configured. Set up the Struts servlet with servlet-mapping `*.do`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you need to define some action mappings in your `struts.xml` that redirects to your view. You can't access the JSPs directly if you're using struts tags in your JSP.

**Edit**

You have updated your question with new `web.xml` content, so the above is covered. However, you still can't access the JSPs directly. You need to add an action mapping that forwards to your view.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Nilsh I tried that too but it aint worked for me

Comment: In that case, show the complete contents of `struts.xml` and the URL you're trying to access.

Comment: I have uploaded the war file in below URL
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g6daddfa41e8981249992832312c465146f9b6bc45

Comment: I will give a up vote thanks for the help u thought to offer Thank u so much

Comment: But how are you accessing the page? What is the URL you type into your browser? My point is that you can't access it with `http://host:port/index.jsp`, since you wouldn't go through the struts action servlet then, and you would get all sorts of exceptions.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. For reference, please post your solution, or accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have `html:link` tag attribute `forward` wrong.

According to the [Struts `link` tag specification](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#link):

> *forward* - Use the value of this attribute as the name of a global ActionForward to be looked up, and use the module-relative or
>   context-relative URI found there. If the forward is module-relative
>   then it must point to an action and NOT to a page.

So, your global forward should point to a Struts Action and not a page.

I hope this resolves your problem.

See a related example [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.struts.doc/topics/cstrdoc006.html).